# Масштабирование элементов по ширине, с одинаковой высотой

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется форма, которая может принимать любой размер. На этой форме есть 7 `TextBlock` с текстом разной длины. Необходимо, чтобы `TextBlock` растягивались по всей ширине формы соблюдая следующее параметры:

- Если в `TextBlock` 1 символ, то он должен быть квадратом.
- У всех `TextBlock` должна быть одинаковая высота и одинаковый размер шрифта.

`Grid` не подошёл, так как мне нужны одинаковые расстояния между `TextBlock`. Так же пробовал `UniformGrid` но он просто растягивает элементы, делая их разными по высоте. Пробовал `Viewbox`, но у меня не получилось добиться нужных результатов.

Как можно добиться желаемого результата при помощи вёрстки? У меня есть вариант с событием на изменение размера формы вручную изменять размеры `TextBlock`, но мне кажется это костылём. Мне в WPF довольно трудно разбираться, так что решил спросить.

Код формы:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="150" Width="500"
        WindowStyle="None"
        FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0">
        <Border Background="#FF323232" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30">
            <TextBlock Text="Rafd Hiljo" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="7" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FF323232" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30">
            <TextBlock Text="MD" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="7" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FF323232" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30">
            <TextBlock Text="T" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="7" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FF323232" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30">
            <TextBlock Text="Lader" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="7" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FF323232" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30">
            <TextBlock Text="W" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="7" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FF323232" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30">
            <TextBlock Text="Q" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="7" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FF323232" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30">
            <TextBlock Text="PAT" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="7" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Форма:

[image: исходный дизайн элементов]

Чего хотелось бы добиться (стрелки с одинаковым цветом - равны):

[image: желаемый дизайн элементов]

Comment: А вот текст самих элементов известен в момент запуска программы?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, Он изменяется во время работы. В основном текст состоит длиной от 1 до 10 символов.

Comment: А сами текстовые элементы, а не их содержимое, создаются тоже во время запуска программы или нет?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, нет сами элементы будут на форме.

Comment: Шрифт возьмите моношинный

Comment: @Jagailo Обновил ответ с учётом динамически изменяемого текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь крайне рекомендую хранить все повторяющиеся значения свойств в стилях ресурсов, что отражено в коде решения.

Для решения данной задачи использовал `Grid`. В элементах, где текст один символ, надо использовать задавать ширину соотвествующей колонки `Auto`, в остальных случаях — `*`.

Также для `Border` следуют удалить `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` чтобы элемент нормально растягивался (чтобы осталось значение по умолчанию `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`).

Результат:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#323232" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border>
        <TextBlock Text="Rafd Hiljo" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="MD" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBlock Text="T" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="3">
        <TextBlock Text="Lader" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="4">
        <TextBlock Text="W" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="5">
        <TextBlock Text="Q" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="6">
        <TextBlock Text="PAT" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

### Динамически изменяемый текст

Для того, чтобы можно было бы динамически изменять содержимое текста и менялся размер столбца используем Binding и написаний нами Converter:

```
public class TextToColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        new GridLength(1, ((string)value).Length == 1 ? GridUnitType.Auto :  GridUnitType.Star);

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Код XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#323232" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
        <local:TextToColumnWidthConverter x:Key="TextToColumnWidthConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=t1, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToColumnWidthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=t2, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToColumnWidthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=t3, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToColumnWidthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=t4, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToColumnWidthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=t5, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToColumnWidthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=t6, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToColumnWidthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=t7, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToColumnWidthConverter}}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border>
        <TextBlock Name="t1" Text="Rafd Hiljo" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Name="t2" Text="MD" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBlock Name="t3" Text="T" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="3">
        <TextBlock Name="t4" Text="Lader" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="4">
        <TextBlock Name="t5" Text="W" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="5">
        <TextBlock Name="t6" Text="Q" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="6">
        <TextBlock Name="t7" Text="PAT" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Но если все `TextBlock` будут длиной в 1 символ. Они примут не будут растягиваться, а останутся 30x30.

Comment: @Jagailo Не понял последнего комментария. Ну да, они не будут растягиваться, если все будут длиной в 1 символ, всё верно. А что вы хотите сказать?

Comment: В вопросе я писал, чтобы высота была одинаковой, но элементы должны масштабироваться и не только по ширине. То есть раз есть место по высоте и по ширине, то и квадраты (с одним символом) должны растянуться по всей ширине. Возможно, это только кодом делается

Comment: @Jagailo Растягивать по высоте получается надо только в случае если все элементы являются квадратами, верно? То есть, в остальных случаях приложение работает верно?